# Как вывести значение JSON файла в тег input

Tags: javascript, html, json, input, tag

Может вопрос и очень тупой, но всё же
Как мне строку из JSON файла занести в input, что бы в дальнейшем получить возможность редактировать её?

```
$('#wrapper').empty();
    $('#name').append($('<input>',
    {
        value: key,
        text :  JSON.stringify(database[key.selectedIndex].name),
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let jsn = {
  "text":"some text"
};
$('#wrapper').append($('<input>').val(jsn.text));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'></div>
```